# Balance in data list is not reduced when it should

Tags: python

I want to make electricity payments by reducing the balance in the data list with bills in the electricity list.

```
data = [{"norek":"932012042", "name":"Ahmad Sujagad",    "balance":5000000},
        {"norek":"932012052", "name":"Basuki Pepeh",     "balance":4000000},
        {"norek":"932012099", "name":"Bambang Gentolet", "balance":3500000}]

data_ele =[{"noseri":"7932392", "name":"Ahmad Sujagad",    "bill":320000},
           {"noseri":"7932384", "name":"Basuki Pepeh",     "bill":250000},
           {"noseri":"7932345", "name":"Bambang Gentolet", "bill":180000}]
```

When I do transactions, the balance is reduced, but when I choose option 1, why is it not reduced?

```
print("1.Electric\n2.Water")
option = int(input("Please Select Menu :"))
if option == 1:
    print("total bill : ",dlist['bill'])
    bayar = input("Are You Sure You're Paying? (Y/T)")
    if bayar == "Y" or bayar == "y":
        print("No Seri : ",dlist['noseri'],"\n","name :",dlist['name'])
        print("your remaining balance  :",duser['balance']-dlist['bill'])
    elif bayar == "T" or bayar == "t":
        print("Payment Cancelled")
```

Console:

```
Please Select Menu :1
total bill :  320000
Are You Sure You're Paying? (Y/T)y
No Seri :  7932392 
name : Ahmad Sujagad

your remaining balance  : 4680000
```

when I check back in the option one, the balance is not reduced:

```
if option == 1:
    print("your remaining balance :",duser['balance'])
```

Console:

```
Please Select Menu :1
your remaining balance : 5000000
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following line:

```
print("your remaining balance  :",duser['balance']-dlist['bill'])
```

...you are only *showing* the result, but you are not *updating* the balance. Replace this line with:

```
duser['balance'] -= dlist['bill']  #  update!
print("your remaining balance  :", duser['balance'])  # show new balance
```